# Copy data from a workbook to an existing workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on Excel for Mac, v16.53, with OS Catalina v10.15.7

I have an Excel workbook called SCRIPT with two sheets.
Sheet 1 has data entry areas and sheet 2 compiles those entries into a pseudo-table. The data in sheet 1 changes with every new person that is interviewed.
The data in sheet 2 is in columns A, B, H, I and J. It is non-contiguous and doesn't always have row 1 populated.

I can copy those five columns to a new csv file called Telesales-Leads-TODAY'S DATE.
The issue is when there already is a Telesales-Leads-TODAY'S DATE file.

The script is supposed to:

1. If Telesales-Leads-TODAY'S DATE file does not exist:
   Start a new one.
   Copy/paste the new SCRIPT data and save the Telesales-Leads-TODAY'S DATE file.
2. If a Telesales-Leads-TODAY'S DATE file does exist:
   Copy the new data from the SCRIPT workbook to the first 100% empty column  of the Telesales-Leads-TODAY'S DATE file.
   Save the file with the same name (Telesales-Leads-TODAY'S DATE) in csv format.

It throws an error AFTER it copies the data from the SCRIPT workbook but BEFORE it has a chance to completely open the Telesales-Leads-TODAY'S DATE file.

I am using the MsgBox to debug.

```vb
Sub BackUpScriptData()
 
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strFileExists As String
Dim finalcolumn As Integer
Dim firstemptycolumn As Integer
Dim csvOpened As Workbook
Dim oneCell As Range
Dim myCSVFileName As String
Dim myWB As Workbook
Dim tempWB As Workbook
Dim rngToSave As Range
Dim col As String
Dim ColumnNumber As Integer
Dim ColumnLetter As String
Dim colstart As String
Dim CellAddress As String
Dim TestChar As String
Dim NumberToLetter As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error GoTo err

strFileName = "/Users/XXXXXXXX/Library/Group Containers/XXXXXXXX.Office/User Content.localized/Startup.localized/Excel/" & "Telesales-Leads-" & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".csv"
strFileExists = Dir(strFileName)

If strFileExists = "" Then
MsgBox strFileName & " ~~~~~~~~doesn't exist"
    Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
    myCSVFileName = "/Users/XXXXXXXX/Library/Group Containers/XXXXXXXX.Office/User Content.localized/Startup.localized/Excel/" & "Telesales-Leads-" & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".csv"

    Set rngToSave = Range("A1:B69,H1:J69")
    rngToSave.Copy

    Set tempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    With tempWB
        .Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .SaveAs FileName:=myCSVFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close
    End With

Else
    Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set rngToSave = Range("A1:B69,H1:J69")
    rngToSave.Copy
    
    Set csvOpened = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=strFileName)

MsgBox "csvOpened is " & csvOpened
        
    With csvOpened
        Set oneCell = Range("A1")

        Do While WorksheetFunction.CountA(oneCell.EntireColumn)
            Set oneCell = oneCell.Offset(0, 1)
        Loop

MsgBox "oneCell.Column is " & oneCell.Column
        
    End With
         
    CellAddress = Cells(1, ColNum).Address
    For i = 2 To Len(CellAddress)
        TestChar = Mid(CellAddress, i, 1)
        If TestChar = "$" Then Exit For
        NumberToLetter = NumberToLetter & Mid(CellAddress, i, 1)
    Next i

MsgBox "colstart is " & colstart
        
    With csvOpened
        .Sheets(1).Range(colstart & "1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .SaveAs FileName:=myCSVFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close
    End With
        
End If

err: MsgBox "failed to copy."
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: _it throws an error_ - What error did you get? what's the code and description and on which line? Did you step through the code line by line?

Comment: I don’t know what the error was; it bounced to the end of the script at err: MsgBox "failed to copy.” which is just a generic error message box I found online. I don’t know how to “step through the code line by line.”

Comment: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code, basically - with your insertion point at sub `BackUpScriptData`, press F8 and you will see a yellow line, pressing F8 again will step through the code line by line. comment out `On Error GoTo err` first before doing that so that you can see the error code and description. @BlackBeard

Comment: `CellAddress = Cells(1, ColNum).Address` ? `ColNum` is not declared or assigned, `ColumnNumber` is declared but not used.

Comment: Seems like a situation to say this: Please insert `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to help you enforce variable declaration (and indirectly catch typo of variable). @Blackbeard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is essentially the same for creating a new workbook or updating an existing, the only difference being the column where the data is to be pasted. As this is a csv file then UsedRange is a simple way to determine the last clear column.

```vb
Sub BackUpScriptData2()

    Const FOLDER = "/Users/XXXXXXXX/Library/Group Containers/XXXXXXXX.Office/" & _
                  "User Content.localized/Startup.localized/Excel/"
    Const PREFIX = "Telesales-Leads-"
 
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbCSV As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rngToSave As Range
    Dim colNum As Long, myCSVFileName As String

    myCSVFileName = PREFIX & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".csv"
    
    ' check if file exists
    If Len(Dir(FOLDER & myCSVFileName)) = 0 Then
        ' not exists
        MsgBox "'" & myCSVFileName & "'" & vbCrLf & _
               "does not exist, it will be created", vbInformation, FOLDER
        Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Add()
        colNum = 1
    Else
        ' exists
        Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER & myCSVFileName)
        With wbCSV.Sheets(1).UsedRange
            colNum = .Column + .Columns.Count
        End With
        MsgBox "'" & myCSVFileName & "'" & vbCrLf & _
               "exists, it will extended from column " & colNum, vbInformation, FOLDER
    End If

    ' copy and save
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngToSave = ws.Range("A1:B69,H1:J69")
    rngToSave.Copy

    With wbCSV
        .Sheets(1).Cells(1, colNum).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .SaveAs Filename:=FOLDER & myCSVFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close False
    End With
    MsgBox "File saved to " & myCSVFileName, vbInformation, FOLDER

End Sub
```